# Use Python scapy to send TCP RST to prevent client access problems

Tags: python, scapy

I used SCAPY to write a program deployed in the WEB server and would like to send TCP RST using SCAPY to block some specific HTTP client access.

After running the program, the client uses Telnet to connect to the server WEB listening port can be SCAPY program interrupt, but the use of browser access can not interrupt. Why is it so?

The code is as follows:

```
# coding: utf-8

# web server  : 10.28.16.20 ;
# http client : 10.28.1.70;

from scapy.all import *
def pkgs(pkg):
    if pkg.getlayer(TCP) and pkg[IP].dst=="10.28.16.20" and "10.28.1.70" in pkg[IP].src:
        resp=IP(dst=pkg[IP].src,src=pkg[IP].dst)/TCP(dport=pkg[TCP].sport,sport=pkg[TCP].dport,flags="RA",seq=pkg[TCP].ack,ack=pkg[TCP].seq+(len(pkg[TCP].payload) if pkg.getlayer(Raw) else 1))
        send(resp,count=2,verbose=0)
if __name__=="__main__":
    conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
    sniff(filter="tcp",prn=pkgs,store=0)
```

[Program code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWvP.jpg)

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, not in comments!

Comment: Code has been added@Thierry Lathuille

Comment: why nobody answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to get into "Scapy"
then paste that code and enter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *
ip = IP(src="10.28.16.20", dst="10.28.1.70")
tcp = TCP(sport=80, dport=@@@@, flags=@@@@, seq=@@@@, ack=@@@@)
pkt = ip/tcp
ls(pkt)
send(pkt,verbose=0)
```

You need to change **dport** to the source port from the PC, **flags** to the action you want to do, **seq&ack** follow the packets you started from.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it.import threading.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you solved it.